# mod_rewrite remove subfolder and php

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make my url go from

root.com/sub/?page=home

TO

root.com/home

I want to remove the subfolder, remove the php and just leave the most basic url.
Also if possible i want to redirect all non 'root.com/[*]' back to root.com.
For example 'root.com/home/index.php?page=home' and 'root.com/sub/test/' would both redirect back to 'root.com'.

.htaccess and mod_rewrite seems to be the best way
So far i have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#remove subfolder, WORKS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^root\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.root\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule (.*) /sub/$1 [L]
```

This works and removed the subfolder

```
#remove PHP, not working :S
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But this is not working and leaves the '?page=home' ect
I think im missing something before the regex for the second rule, but im new to this.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: taken into account the [L] thing, still no dice.

I'm guessing it needs to be done in one hit rather then seperate iterations.

Comment: bump / i found another problem, when i view the site from my computer it (the first part) shows as 'www.root.com/page' which is good, but on my mates computer it shows up as 'www.root.com/sub/page' wtf.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of `mod_write` usually lies on conflicts; in this case, the second block will be matched by the first block append afterword, creating an infinite loop or 500 error.

You should append the flag `[L]` to every `RewriteRule`. E.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
#remove subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^root\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.root\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule (.*) /sub/$1 [L]

#remove PHP
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Without `[L]`, `/abc` will be rewrite to `/index.php?page=abc`, and that will rewrite to `/sub//index.php?page=abc`.

I am 75% sure this is the problem, but it's untested so I am not going to bet on it. Never hurt trying though.

Comment: i gave it a go, but i still get a url like "www.root.com/?page=home" so the subfolder ramains gone but the php is still around

Answer (score 0):

This rule is the problem I think:

`RewriteRule (.*) /sub/$1 [L]`

Try changing it to:

`RewriteRule (.*) /sub/index.php?page=$1 [L]`